# how to calculate the 4 days before date of the target date

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, datetime, date

i have two dates

ValidFrom : 20-04-2010

validTo   : 02-05-2010

i need to know 4 days(date) before the validity expire .how to calculate the 4 days before date of the validity expire  date  02-05-2010

Comment: why SQL tag? would you prefer SQL solution?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
var dt = new DateTime(2010, 5, 2);
var fourDaysBefore = dt.AddDays(-4);
```

If that's not what you mean, you're going to have to be much more specific.

Answer (score 1):

I can't really tell what the context of the question is but this is one way to do it if you were trying to do it in mysql.

```
SELECT ADDDATE('2010-05-02', INTERVAL -4 DAY);
```